# Calculating the frequency of each list item in another list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get the frequency in which the last digit of a list appears in a list, and having quite a bit a of trouble.

basically this is the function that I am trying to create:

```
>>> ones_digit_histogram([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765])
[0.09523809523809523, 0.19047619047619047, 0.047619047619047616, 0.14285714285714285, 0.14285714285714285, 0.14285714285714285, 0, 0.14285714285714285, 0.047619047619047616, 0.047619047619047616]
```

and this is what I have so far

```
def last_digit(number):
    last_digit = str(number)[-1]
    last_digit = int(last_digit)
    return last_digit

def ones_digit_of_each_list_item(num_list):    
    returned_list = []
    for list_value in num_list:
        returned_list = (returned_list + [last_digit(list_value)])

    return returned_list

print ones_digit_of_each_list_item([123, 32, 234, 34, 22])
```

The trouble I am having involves getting the result of

```
ones_digit_of_each_list_item([123, 32, 234, 34, 22])
```

to be included in finding the frequency of occurrence (in the form of a percentage) in the list `[123, 32, 234, 34, 22]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last digit of a number is the remainder of the division of the number by ten, so you can use the `%` operator to compute it more efficiently.

When building the result list, instead of concatenating list, it is better to `.append()` the new value to the new list. Or even better to use a list comprehension.

```
def last_digit(number):
    return number % 10

def one_digit_of_each_list_number(number_list):
    return [last_digit(number) for number in number_list]
```

Then, you only have to count the number of occurrences of each digit (there are only ten digits possible, so it is better to use a list than a dictionary), and then divide by the total number of items.

```
def ones_digit_histogram(number_list):
    histogram = [0] * 10
    for digit in one_digit_of_each_list_number(number_list):
        histogram[digit] += 1
    return [float(x)/len(number_list) for x in histogram]
```

Then, for your exemple, you'll get:

```
>>> print ones_digit_histogram([123, 32, 234, 34, 22])
[0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Digit `1` occurs once in your last example, so the result for it cannot be `0.0`.

Comment: It never occur in last position as asked by the OP.